# how to call soap webservice of database in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap

How to call web service of soap for database in android.

My web service is in ASP.NET in C#.

why NewDataSet and Table  values not showing up in soap web service in android
Please Answer.

$    package com.example.asp_qrcode;

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView output;
EditText treeid;
Button ok;
String s;
     private final String NAMESPACE = "tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://cafe-wb.com/QRCODE/service1.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SP_GET_TREE_NAME_BY_TREEID";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "SP_GET_TREE_NAME_BY_TREEID";
    String resultString;
    SoapObject response;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text2);
    treeid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    s = treeid.getText().toString();

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
                    PropertyInfo treeIDProp =new PropertyInfo();
                    treeIDProp.setName("TREE_ID");
                    treeIDProp.setValue(s);
                    treeIDProp.setType(int.class);
                    request.addProperty(treeIDProp);


                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                    //Log.i("Envelop: ",);

                    try {
                        //androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
                        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                        response=(SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                        //response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
                       resultString= androidHttpTransport.responseDump;

                      //  resultString = response.toString();

                        //resultString = ((SoapObject)response.getPropertySafely("sequence")).getPropertySafely("element").toString(); 

                        //SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                        Log.i("Result: ",resultString);

                        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                output.setText(resultString);

                           }
                       });          



                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            };

            thread.start();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

My Web service Result is:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"       xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="TREE_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PARENT_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TREE_NAME" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TYPE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DISCRIPTION" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="DATE_ADDED" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Page" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<TREE_ID>56</TREE_ID>
<PARENT_ID>41</PARENT_ID>
<TREE_NAME>P.T.F.E Envelope Gaskets</TREE_NAME>
<TYPE>P.T.F.E GASKETS</TYPE>
<DISCRIPTION>
<p><strong>PTFE Envelope Gaskets</strong>&nbsp;provided by us are largely used in various industries in different processes and purposes. We offer these PTFE Envelope Gaskets in two types namely Milled type and slit type. These gaskets can have inserts of CAF, Rubber, Corrugated steel sandwiched between CAF rings, PVC. The clients can avail the PTFE Envelope Gaskets manufactured by us in varied specifications, shapes, and sizes as per their requirements.</p> <p>&nbsp;</p> <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> <p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p> <p><strong>Milled Type</strong></p> <ul> <li>It is made to fit the insert and presents a flat face to the flange</li> <li>Fused End envelopes are being manufactured from Diameters of 400mm to any size with a maximum wall thickness of upto 100mm</li> </ul> <p><br /> <strong>Slit Type</strong></p> <ul> <li>The envelope in this variety does not present a full face to the flange</li> </ul> <p>It is perfectly adequate for varied applications&nbsp;</p>
</DISCRIPTION>
<DATE_ADDED>2013-06-10T13:54:56.41+05:30</DATE_ADDED>
<Page>1</Page>
</Table>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Comment: soap service for database?! i really don't get what you want

Comment: Hi..You are calling webservice using SOAP. have you created API in C#?Any error in log cat?Wht is the issue?

Comment: Are you sure the given SOAP_ACTION,NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME,URL is correct?

Answer (score 1):

ok.. First of all when you are doing Coding for Network side or Server side It is good Practice of Using **AsynTask**

So I show you how you actully do your code.

```
public class ExampleClass extends Activity {

    SoapObject result;

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope_test = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    Button btn_callService;
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;


    public String NAMESPACE = "tempuri.org/";
    public  String URL = "http://cafe-wb.com/QRCODE/service1.asmx";
    public  String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SP_GET_TREE_NAME_BY_TREEID";
    public  String METHOD_NAME = "SP_GET_TREE_NAME_BY_TREEID";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.absence);
     btn_callService= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Approve1);
}


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {

        btn_callService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    new ShowDialogAsyncTask ().execute();   

        });

        super.onStart();

    }



    public class ShowDialogAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ExampleClass.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // update the UI immediately after the task is executed
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            callingNotificationDet(envelope_test);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                dialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            retrieveNotificationDet(envelope_test);

        }
        public void callingNotificationDet(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope){



        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("TREE_ID",""+s); //( s = treeid.getText().toString();) set your property here
        request.addProperty(); // set your property here

        // create header
        Element[] header = new Element[1];
        header[0] = new Element()
                .createElement(
                        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                        "Security");
        header[0].setAttribute(null, "mustUnderstand", "1");

        Element usernametoken = new Element()
                .createElement(
                        "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd",
                        "UsernameToken");
        usernametoken.setAttribute(null, "Id", "UsernameToken-1");
        header[0].addChild(Node.ELEMENT, usernametoken);

        Element username = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Username");
        username.addChild(Node.IGNORABLE_WHITESPACE, userName);
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);

        Element pass = new Element().createElement(null, "n0:Password");
        pass.setAttribute(
                null,
                "Type",
                "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
        pass.addChild(Node.TEXT, password);
        usernametoken.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, pass);

        // add header to envelope
        envelope.headerOut = header;
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.bodyOut = request;

        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); // Calling

        } catch (SoapFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
  public void retrieveAction(SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope)
{
    SoapObject result;
    try {
        result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        String res = result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();

    }
    catch (SoapFault e) {

    }

}
    }

}
```

Make Sure Your all NameSpace,Method Name.URL are correct

Comment: I print res = result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString();

        Log.v("Result: ",res); but i got not proper result.

Comment: Result is....
V/Result: (  816): anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{el
ement=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=an
yType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyTyp
e{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }

Comment: String res = result.getPropertyAsString(0).toString(); this will give you first record

Comment: Is Service is call?? Print result in Log. like Log.d("Result",""+result) and chk in log cat!

Comment: when i call the webservice from crome it give me full page with tables data but when i call programmatically in android it give just schema and not tables data. like NewDataElement,Table,TREE_ID,PARENT_ID...etc.

Comment: The service called by you is also made by you in C#?

Comment: D/Result: (  865): anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{el
ement=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=an
yType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyType{}; element=anyTyp
e{}; element=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }

Comment: Have you set Property? the data which you want to get that should be set in Property.

Comment: it is the same result after of Log.d("Result",result). In browser that show value of table data. In your code i have ommit header and username , usernameToaken ,pass portion of data.Becuase it gives error at runtime.

Comment: thts okie.. it was security header.. If you have used Authentication it was for tht..

Comment: Property means the value which is needed for retrieve the data.